# Set new value on attributes in a namespace

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have this xml (it is a part of a more extended one) that I'm parsing using python and lxml

```
<om:OM_Observation gml:id="observation">
 <gml:description>Wind Speed</gml:description>     
 <om:phenomenonTime xlink:href="#phenomenonTime"/>
 <om:resultTime xlink:href="#phenomenonTime"/>
 <om:procedure xlink:href="procedure"/>
 <om:observedProperty xlink:href="WS_5min_avg"/>
 <om:featureOfInterest xlink:href="#FOI"/>
 <om:result xsi:type="gml:MeasureType" uom="m/s">568</om:result>
</om:OM_Observation>
```

I'm able to get the text value within the tags and change its value and update the file data.xml:

```
from lxml import etree
data='data.xml'
data_tree = etree.parse(data)
root = data_tree.getroot()
nsmap = {'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',  'gml': 'http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2',  'om': 'http://www.opengis.net/om/2.0'}

result=data_tree.xpath("//om:OM_Observation/om:result", namespaces=nsmap)
result[0].text="114"    
etree.ElementTree(root).write(data, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method="xml", pretty_print=True)
```

What I would like to do is to change the value of the attribute and update the xml file. 
I'm trying a similar approach but it is not working. I'm able to get the value of the attribute:

```
 featureOfInterest_attr=tree.xpath("//om:featureOfInterest/@xlink:href", namespaces=nsmap)
```

but if I would like to change its value using:

```
tree.xpath("//om:featureOfInterest/@xlink:href",namespaces=nsmap)="#newFOI"
etree.ElementTree(root).write(data, xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8', method='xml', pretty_print=True)
```

the new value is not inserted.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last code snippet has a crucial difference from your successful code. `xpath()` returns list, so you have to specify which item in the list need to be updated by using index :

```
result = tree.xpath("//om:featureOfInterest/@xlink:href",namespaces=nsmap)
result[0] = "#newFOI"
# or
# tree.xpath("//om:featureOfInterest/@xlink:href",namespaces=nsmap)[0] = "#newFOI"
```

---

Apparently, we can't update attributes that was directly selected using `xpath()`, since the return value is just a list of string. So in this case `result[0] = ...` only update value of the first item of the list and doesn't affect the source XML tree at all. We need to get the parent of the attribute instead and then update from there :

```
result = tree.xpath("//om:featureOfInterest",namespaces=nsmap)
result[0].attrib['{%s}href' % nsmap['xlink']] = "#newFOI"
```

Comment: Hi @har07 you are right. thanks for this first suggestion. But, unfortunately, i'm still not able to update the xml file with the new attribute value. Am I still missing something?

Comment: did you write your `data_tree` back to the disk/file after modification?

Comment: yes, I did as indicated in the post
     etree.ElementTree(root).write(data.xml, xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8', method='xml', pretty_print=True)

Comment: How about `data_tree.write(...)` ? i.e without creating new `ElementTree`

Comment: Hi @har07 Unfortunately even using _data_tree.write(...)_ it does not change the final output of the xml file